# How to check if file is already opened using boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

How to check if file is already opened using boost if file is not opened then removed that file other wise do nothing

```
boost::filesystem::wpath file("c://test.txt");

if(boost::filesystem::exists(file))
{
   if(here i want a check that file is already open or not, if open then run else)
   {
     boost::filesystem::remove(file);
   }
   else
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: How are you going to deal with situations, where the file is opened in between your check and your attempt to remove it?

Comment: if its open then i dont want to remove it .

Comment: thats why i put comment and there i want to implement some code that if file is opened than dont remove it.

Comment: @ArslanAhmed  IInspectable's point is: What if the file is *not* open when you check (so you're going to remove it), but it *is* open by the time you try to remove it?

Comment: @MikeKinghan thanks for point that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the job of the OS to prevent/allow this.

Each OS has it's own ways of locking for exclusive use, in which case deletion will fail anyways.

Other OSes (POSIX) will unlink the file entry from the inode, and the file keeps remaining accessible to the processes that have the file opened. When the last use of the inode goes away, the file is actually deleted.

In short, don't try to detect up front, just see whether deletion failed. Otherwise you'll run into the race condition mentioned

> *How are you going to deal with situations, where the file is opened in between your check and your attempt to remove it?* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404800/how-to-check-if-file-is-already-opened-using-boost/31405355#comment50783372_31404800)

<sub>It seems you have missed the point of that (seeing your reply), and Mike explained</sub>

Comment: If file is already opened then do nothing and if not open then delete that file.

Comment: You can, only by trying. (I'm afraid that repeating the question will not help you understand the answer.)

Comment: @ArslanAhmed: See [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) for a more elaborate explanation.